# display recents posts on single post page and exclude active single post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developping a website on wordpess.

I have a page displaying all the news title (posts titles).
when clicking on one title, I'm directed to the single posts page.
I want to display on every single posts page the 5 most recents posts title at the bottom of my single posts pages.
it works fine using this code.

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

<?php the_time('y-m-d'); ?> 
<?php the_title(); ?> 
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

what I would like to do is to exclude the active single post I'm reading of the 5 most recents posts, otherwise my posts is displayed twice...

anyone know if it's possible and how I can achieve this ?

thanks for your help,

Comment: add  WP_Query( 'showposts=5&orderby=asc' )

Answer (score 0):

```
  $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5,
                  'post__not_in'   => $post->ID
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

 the_time('y-m-d');
 the_title(); 
 the_content(); 
endwhile;  wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

pass the  $post->ID to the  post_not_in  array

id will get the current post id

Comment: thanks for your help @Vickey... I don't know where to add this code, I'm not very familiar with php... here is jsfiddle, can you please help me ?
http://jsfiddle.net/7NGZF/

Comment: i updated the code now you can replace it where you are previously useing it

Comment: thanks @Vickey... but I'm getting a error... it displays this : WARNING: ARRAY_MAP() [FUNCTION.ARRAY-MAP]: ARGUMENT #2 SHOULD BE AN ARRAY IN /HOMEZ.743/ROCKONBO/WWW/WP-INCLUDES/QUERY.PHP ON LINE 2416

WARNING: IMPLODE() [FUNCTION.IMPLODE]: INVALID ARGUMENTS PASSED IN /HOMEZ.743/ROCKONBO/WWW/WP-INCLUDES/QUERY.PHP ON LINE 2416

Comment: add    wp_reset_query()  at end of this code  after end while

Comment: I still get the same error...WARNING: ARRAY_MAP() [FUNCTION.ARRAY-MAP]: ARGUMENT #2 SHOULD BE AN ARRAY IN /HOMEZ.743/ROCKONBO/WWW/WP-INCLUDES/QUERY.PHP ON LINE 2416

WARNING: IMPLODE() [FUNCTION.IMPLODE]: INVALID ARGUMENTS PASSED IN /HOMEZ.743/ROCKONBO/WWW/WP-INCLUDES/QUERY.PHP ON LINE 2416

Comment: i edu=ited the code again it lasly have one extra comma  sorry  check now

Comment: still get the same error. here is my code : 
<?php $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5,
                  'post__not_in'   => $post->ID
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

 the_time('y-m-d');
 the_title(); 
 the_content(); 
endwhile;  wp_reset_query();  ?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46677/discussion-between-user2882154-and-vickey)

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_post for that

Example:

```
<?php
$post = get_post($id); //assuming $id has been initialized
setup_postdata($post);

// display the post here
the_title();
the_excerpt();
the_post_thumbnail();

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: // Include the wp-load'er
include('wp-load.php');

// Get the last 10 posts
// Returns posts as arrays instead of get_posts' objects
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
 'numberposts' => 10
));
 
// Do something with them
echo '<ul>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
 echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

Comment: hello thanks @kuldip Makadiya for your answer but I don't understand what I'm supposed to change on my code... I'm not really familiar with php... thanks a llot

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, here is the code :

```
<?php $args = $args = array(
     'numberposts' => 5,
     'offset' => 0,
     'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
   );

  $myposts2 = get_posts($args);

 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();?>

     <div class="news">
     <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
     <?php the_time('y-m-d'); ?>
     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     </div>

<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

thank you all for your help